# Is it good to add @Component or @Bean in POJO classes in Java?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

***My Scope of the object is in Method level***, Is it good to decorate a POJO class with
@Componet or @Bean with scope request or prototype, So that we could inject it in the required class to avoid Object Instantiation by manual.

Is it a good practice?

Comment: POJO's should not have anny annotation

Comment: Thanks Jens, what about the bean validation annotations that are available to validate in server side? are you saying like we should not use such in the modal objects(POJOs)

Answer (score 9):

### What to annotate?

Within the Spring Framework, only use the @Bean annotation in classes marked with @Configuration.

Although possible to use the @Bean within @Component classes, it is not recommended, since you will be creating light beans (Which is considered bad practice and can lead to unintended side effects).

### When to use @Bean vs @Component?

The golden rule, use @Component (Or @Service) in your own classed, and @Configuration + @Bean for third-party code.

### What not to annotate with @Component or @Bean

Do not annotate domain classes or Entities (For example your person class), only classes that are considered to be stateless. (Like your ManagerPerson / **Service class).

*Do not annotate your DTOs.*

If you have any of these currently annotated, I would strongly recommend first jumping back to Spring Framework tutorials.

### What about scope?

Go have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

There are only a couple namely:

- **Singleton (Default scope)** Single Spring Bean Instance for the application - Same Instance that is being used all over the application.)
- **Prototype** (New bean for where ever it is used)
- **Request** (Spring Bean per Request only for Spring MVC)
- **Session** (Spring Bean per Session only for Spring MVC)
- **Custom Scope** (Yes you can create your own... but don't ;) )